# Laravel: what happens if I have separate read/write connections configured, and do both reads and writes within a transaction?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, transactions, laravel-5

If I have reads/writes configured in `database.php`, and I start a transaction like `DB::transaction(function() { // series of reads and writes })`, will everything run on the `write` connection, or will there be two separate transactions, or will it just explode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying you want to do both reads and writes within a transaction **using the same connection**, then that will work fine - you can read from the database during the transaction.

If you're saying you want to read using one connection while you're writing as part of a transaction on the other connection, that will work fine too although you might have times when the read connection will block until the write connection transaction is finished.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3272

`getReadPdo()` now checks if the query is within a transaction, and in that case returns the same PDO connection as the write.